# Are there any good general topology video lectures on these topics?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, self-learning, learning, online-resources

I'm preparing for one exam on General Topology for which I need to self study. The topics that will be covered in the exam are:

> Metric spaces, topological spaces, continuous functions, product space, quotient space. Convergence of nets and filters. Hausdorff spaces, regular and normal spaces. Compactness and connectedness. Homotopy, fundamental group. Covering spaces.

Are there any good video lectures online on General Topology that cover these topics?

Comment: Just a remark: the fundamental group and covering spaces are getting into *algebraic* topology, although your question specifies *general* topology.

Comment: I dont think that a video will be useful for learn these topics, because they have too much content. Indeed will be very inefficient trying to remember something of a video. Think that a book, the shortest you want, will had a lot more of information than a series of videos.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Masacroso. Based on your comment I've asked separetely in a more general way about how can I prepare for this exam.

Answer (score 1):

1. [**Summer School on Computational Topology and Topological Data Analysis, Ljubljana 2013**](http://videolectures.net/computationaltopology2013_ljubljana/?q=Topology)
2. [**24 lectures on general topology by ohubrismine, posted on Youtube**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpG_ISEhQ6z0Q5MaIvdn5tBJFWfp9fZtQ)

Comment: The second link looks relevant, but the first one does not appear to be about *general topology*.

Answer (score 0):

These lecture videos are very good.

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbMVogVj5nJRR7zYZifYopb52zjoScx1d

Answer (score 0):

A very good lecture series [can befound here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbMVogVj5nJRR7zYZifYopb52zjoScx1d)